# How to convert and timestamp multiple dataframes R

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp

I am having trouble converting the time of data from 4 sensors into something usable in stats models and graphs. I want each sensors' dataframe to have the same system.

Data was collected for about 50 days, and time was recorded in %d%m%y %h/%m.
Each sensor started collecting data on the same day, but at different times.
Also some sensors failed for periods at a time throughout the experiment, and need to account for this while converting the time.

Something like days-hours-minutes-seconds from the first time all sensors were on would make sense. I have looked into strptime and using Julian days, but am unsure how do coordinate this thoughout the 4 dataframes. I also used rbind to create one dataframe of the 4 sensors. would using this better for converting the data?

Edit: added data sample. Each dataframe contains "sensor_id".

```
   time    dht22_t dht11_t dht22_h dht11_h db  pa  treatment_hive  wifi sensor_id
1   01/09/2014 15:19    NA      NA  NA      NA  51.75467    NA      0   1   1   
2   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  59.8    44  55.27682    100672  0   1   1
3   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  60.3    44  54.81995    100675  0   1   1
4   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  60.9    44  54.14134    100671  0   1   1
5   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  61.1    44  53.88574    100672  0   1   1
6   01/09/2014 15:19    30.8    31  61.2    44  53.68800    100680  0   1   1
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? Also consider looking into the `lubridate` package. It makes working through time related problems much easier than base R.

Comment: Yes, sorry, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Re: lubridate - i have been having trouble downloading it. I am using R Version 0.98.1087, but lubridate only works for versions 3 and newer. Using a 32bit linux debain OS and am unsure how to get the right copy of r to use lubridate

Comment: I believe you are referring to the version of RStudio you are using. When you first open R, it should tell you what version you are using on the first line of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `POSIX` functions? Here is an example (timezone is optional):

```
as.POSIXct("01/09/2014 15:19", format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT")
```

Or if you want to replace the column from your data frame:

```
df$time = as.POSIXlt(df$time, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using POSIXct will fundamentally store the data as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.  Assuming your `time` is a string.

```
df$time.posix <-as.POSIXct(time,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",tz="GMT")
```

You have some options from here. For instance you can just use the underlying number of seconds

```
df$time.seconds <- unclass(df$time.posix)
```

Here is the number of seconds since the first observation in `time`.

```
df$time.seconds2 <- unclass(df$time.posix - min(df$time.posix))
```